# Changed attribute set name, now new products wont show up anymore

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I've changed the standard product attribute set name to something else than Default. Than I noticed new products wont show up anymore (yes they are visible, in stock, emptied the cache and new index etc.).

So I changed it back to Default, when I saw you weren't allowed to change the attribute name. But it still doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should keep your attribute set name to be called 'default' as there are circumstances when (if 'default' is not found) another attribute set called 'default' will be created.

However, you are where you are. On Magento Connect there is an extension to update the attribute set of a product (i.e. to change it).

Other attribute set gotchas include configurable products where the daughter products do not show up because they have a different attribute set name to the parent product.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flagbit-change-attribute-set.html

(I believe this works on 1.9.x and EE version 1.14.xx)

Usual caveats apply - test on your development environment first (or take a dump of your database). I have not had problems with this extension, it has 'got me out of jail' a few times over the years.

If you do not like to see the attribute set listed in your products grid, clone the Grid.php file into the local codebase and edit out the column.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've exported 1 product, than deleted it, than re-imported it, but It still wont show up. So I'm getting pretty worried right now. I've installed your plugin and changed the attribute set and back to Default (could it be its written default instead of Default?). But new products still don't show up. Have you got any other option? I think your plugin works, if you use it before the change of name, not after... –